# JWT: handling token auth on a multi-domain-level

Tags: javascript, security, polymer, token, jwt

Currently I'm facing the following problem:

I'm building an application with a standalone login view. 
Let's assume they both run on different domains. My login view communicates with a REST service on the server that issues a JWT token.

With this issued token the user should now be able to view (be forwarded to) the application. But this application - as mentioned - runs on another domain (or subdomain, maybe).

In my mind I tried the following:

1. Token is issued by the server. A hash is stored in a database and the hash is issued to the user. The hash is transferred to the application via URL and the applications checks the hash.
2. Token is issued by the server. The token is transferred to the user. When the user now opens the application (or is forwarded to...) the token should be transferred there, too. I have no clue how to do...

Both are not ideal ways, i know. But I really don't know how I can achieve that...

I hope anyone is able to help me with my thinkings?
If anything is unclear, just comment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc. offer OAuth by redirecting (302 Redirect Request). Basically your app starts if user has a valid token everything is fine, else it will open the Login-Page from the Identity Provider (e.g. Google) and return the token, if the login was successful.

This graphic shows the general steps:

https://www.soapui.org/soapui/media/images/stories/oauth2/oauth2flow.png

Hope this helps.

Lets assume you have two services in 2 different domains. One is your identity provider which generates tokens and holds the token <--> user assignment (we call it: idp.my.company). The other one is any application that does stuff but needs to login via idp.my.company (we call it app.my.company).

You have two scenarios:
 1. Login without having a token aquired before.
 2. Login with token.

1. Request GET: app.my.company
2. Response 302: Moved to: idp.my.company

   - Take a look which redirection type follows your needs (307 maybe)
     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection
   - You need to add an information where to redirect back. In this case app.my.company.
3. [This happens automatically because of the Redirect] GET: idp.my.company/login.html.
4. Response 200 OK: idp.my.company/login.html

   - The User will now see the Login-Page of your IDP-Service and perform a Login.
5. Request POST: idp.my.company/login.html (or whatever)

   - The User posts his credentials to aquire a token
6. Response 302 Redirect: If login is successful, return token and now redirect to the origin site (app.my.company) which you provided earlier.
7. Request GET: app.my.company/afterlogin.html

   - The header contains a valid token
8. Response 200 Ok: Now the app.my.company service needs to check if the token is valid and if true return 200 Ok otherwise redirect again to IDP (start over at step 2).

This should be it. There could be errors but you should have a consistent picture of the process and get a grasp on how to implement it. Those steps cover scenario 1 and 2.

Comment: In fact "I" am the identity provider. I won't use external services :-(

Comment: Yes I know but the solution would be the same. It would be easy to integrate. I have the same issue at my company at the moment and you just helped me to solve my problem :). Where is your problem in understanding this approach? Maybe I can be more concrete.

Comment: If I understand you correct: 1. If the user opens the application and HAS a valid token, everything is fine. 2. If the user does NOT have a valid token, he is redirected to the login (until here: fine!), logs in with credentials and gets a token issued. JWT token? How is this token then "transferred" back to the application? How will the 302 happen? I'm just doing the Login with Polymer...

Comment: I've edited everything. Iam using angular2 which is basically using similar technologies like polymer (create own tags, shadow dom and stuff). Therefore Iam just marking the path on HTTP-Level and you are free to implement it with the technology you want. The idp issues the token and puts it in the redirect header so the client will have the token (I think that should work. Acutally Iam not sure but the internet knows).

Comment: That could work ;-) Just for my understanding for #7: The "header contains a valid token": Request or Response? If Request, how do I pass the token in the header? If Request: how do I check if the token is valid against the user?

Comment: Oh I didn't mention that. In step 5 the user provides the credential. At step 6 the idp checks if login is valid, generates a token if okay and then redirects to the origin as stated and puts the token in the header of the redirect response (step 6) so that the client has the token. Now @ step 7 the user can call the "after login page" and send the token in the header. The token must be provided in each request by the client as you may know and it must be checked by the server everytime. So you don't get around that your app-service needs to contact the idp-service everytime (for each request)

Comment: It should be possible to send information via a redirect. Because the redirect "forces" the client to make a request implicitly you may need to add the header for the "automatic request" manually somehow. Iam not sure how that may work but you'll definitly find an answer online. I have no time to look it up and test it at the moment, sorry for that. In future I will need it myself :P.

Comment: Thanks - I will try and let you know ;-)